# sql collation sorting of nonunicode data for western European languages

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have SQL server 2014 running with default collation i.e. `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Planning to support western European language like German, French, Italian, Portuguese, Spanish along with English.

The database has string data as non-unicode i.e. `varchar`.

I need help to understand whether sorting of the listed languages will work fine with the default collation or what kind of issues can I expect?

Comment: Maybe Duplicated ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310439/sql-server-collation ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039211/what-does-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-do --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538732/what-does-collation-mean

Comment: Thanks. below helped a lot Collation defines how you sort and compare string values

For example, it defines how to deal with

accents (äàa etc)
case (Aa)
the language context:
In a French collation, cote < côte < coté < côté.
In the SQL Server Latin1 default , cote < coté < côte < côté
ASCII sorts (a binary collation) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538732/what-does-collation-mean

Answer (score 2):

The link was very helpful [What does collation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538732/what-does-collation-mean) . Thanks @ahmed abdelqader

Copying part of it:
Collation defines how you sort and compare string values

For example, it defines how to deal with

accents (äàa etc)
case (Aa)

language context:

In a French collation, cote < côte < coté < côté

In the SQL Server Latin1 default , cote < coté < côte < côté

Few of western European languages will be stored and sorted properly with default collation. Special sorting (SQL level- change collation or code level - C# culture) has to be done for French, Spanish, German phonebook
The list of required collation can be seen at:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835499(v=sql.110).aspx